# I cannot preview html in webstorm soft

Tags: webstorm

I can not preview a html file in webstorm 9.0.1 when I run it, it shows `web page is not available` because in addressbar it shows `localhost:63342/---project folder.---`. How can I access from local harddisk html file. 
And, another question can I preview html in google chrome/firefox as docable?

Comment: Do you have running local server?

Comment: I have no idea about local server. I just want to run a simple html file through webstorm. Ie, let i create a new project in webstorm, I open the the .html file and then i just want to run from here.

Comment: You should be able to open the file directly in the browser (File > Open) or you can find it on your machine and choose to open with a browser (right click | open with...)

Comment: No bro i want to open it just click run button.

Comment: Please read what `localhost:63342/PROJECT_NAME/` is about: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Using+the+Built-in+Webserver+in+PhpStorm

Answer (score 0):

To access `http://localhost` you need to have running local server (like XAMPP or WAMPP). If you have no localhost server (or you have no idea if that thing exist in your computer) than you can't access `http://localhost`. That means any `*.php` file will be not usable.
If you are font-end developer, you don't need server. You can access your `*.html` files directly: `file:///C:/path/to/file.html` (in browser site url box). Also, for any external sources to work, path to that file must be relative:

```
//C://myProject
myProject
 |-index.html
 \
  css
   |-styles.css
 \js
   |-functions.js
```

You enter to browser url bar: `file:///C://myProject/index.html`

Your `index.html` looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
        <-- WRONG:
        <script src="http://localhost/js/functions.js"></script>
        <script src="C:/myProject/js/functions.js"></script> // valid, but better to avoid
        -->
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: *"To access http://localhost you need to have running local server (like XAMPP or WAMPP)."* Not really -- PhpStorm/WebStorm comes with **simple** built-in web server which is accessible via `localhost:63342/PROJECT_NAME/` URLs. http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Using+the+Built-in+Webserver+in+PhpStorm

Answer (score 0):

To preview HTML file on disk (using `file:///` protocol) in WebStorm, hold Shift when choosing a browser